# Java equivalent to JavaScript unescape function

Tags: java, javascript, escaping

Is there any function in Java programming language that is equivalent to JavaScript unescape function? That is, if my input is the string "I%20need%20help%21" the output must be "I need help!", for example.

Thanks!

Comment: note that neither JS unescape nor URLDecoder are RFC-3986 compatible http://www.subbu.org/blog/2008/02/uri-escaping-and-javaneturlencoder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `URLDecoder`. Assuming you are using UTF-8:

```
String result = URLDecoder.decode(s, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `java.net.URLDecoder.decode(String s)` is deprecated.

Comment: you need to tell the char encoding as well

Comment: Thanks. Fixed (guessing UTF-8).

Comment: the javascript escape does not use UTF-8, so this does not work for escaped encoding of characters between 129 and 256, e.g. escape('«') == "%AB", but URLDecoder.decode("%AB", "UTF-8") == �

Answer (score 10):

From my experience `URLDecoder.decode` might fail if there are non-ASCII characters in the encoded string. For example this code:

```
URLDecoder.decode("%u017C", "UTF-8"); // %u017C is the result of running in Javascript escape('ż')
```

throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: "u0"
```

The best way of solving this issue that I know of (though clumsy) is just running Javascript in Java :(

```
String jsEscapedString = "%u017C";
ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String result = (String) engine.eval("unescape('" + jsEscapedString + "')");
```

BTW solution inspired by [Siva R Vaka's post](http://blog.sivavaka.com/2010/11/incompatiable-javascripts.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
URLDecoder dec = new URLDecoder();
        String val = dec.decode("I%20need%20help%21","UTF-8");
        System.out.println(val);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is fine @Nrj, but developers are to invoke it staticly.

```
URLDecoder.decode("I%20need%20help%21","UTF-8");
```